# How can you buy XRP with BTC if you don't have any XRP?

Tags: ripple

As far as I know the best way to buy XRP for BTC is from the Ripple client ... which requires some XRP to begin with.

If you own 0 XRP and some BTC, how can you get started acquiring XRP?

Comment: Shortly, gateways should be able to fund accounts for their customers. XRP are in short supply right now, but the giveaway will accelerate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can buy some Ripple (XRP) from [Bitstamp](http://www.bitstamp.net). At the time of writing, they were selling 50 XRP / 1 USD.

Comment: I haven't created an account there, but I can't see any mention of Ripple on their site. Can you provide some more detail as to how this can be done?

Comment: @HighlyIrregular: Arrange to have USD in your Bitstamp balance (deposit BTC and sell some for USD or wire/deposit USD directly) and then go to "Buy/Sell"->"Buy ripples" (or direct to: https://bitstamp.net/market/xrp ). Enter some number of USD and a Ripple address (brand new and un-funded or existing; doesn't matter).

Comment: Note, as of Sept 30th, 2013 Bitstamp requires a verified account to to Ripple deposits.

Answer (score 3):

Dealing with someone directly might be your best bet: he would send you the ripples you need, and you would send him the bitcoins. This works because you don't need ripples to receive ripples.

Another way would be to wait for OpenCoin (Ripple's owners) to open another faucet: the only one opened so far granted some ripples to the users of [Bitcoin's forum](https://bitcointalk.org/).

Comment: It's a bad sad, but Ripple might not directly support what I want in-network. I wonder if there's a technical solution that would.

Comment: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/7939/could-the-ripple-protocol-be-modified-to-allow-funding-your-initial-account-with

Answer (score 2):

You can also purchase XRP for Bitcoin from https://xrptrader.com.

I'm not tied to the service, but it's a very easy way to do it, and the price tends to be reasonable.

Edit: The price has not been so reasonable lately. I would get my initial xrp via Bitstamp:USD.

Answer (score 2):

This is the most complete answer I've seen so far regarding [how to get a Ripple account funded](https://ripple.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2270).

Answer (score -2):

you can also purchase XRP on website : www.ripplewise.com